# \obeylines and verse environment in memoir

Tags: memoir, verse

When I use the \obeylines macro with the verse environment, it prevents line numbering and introduces extra white space between the lines.  Is there a way to address this?

```
\documentclass[ebook]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\obeylines
\linenumberfrequency{10}
\verselinenumbersleft

\begin{verse}
Herman: 
O'er every birth a star of fate presides,
And he that knows his orb of destiny,
May, by the changes of its radiance, tell
Whene'er his good or evil genius reigns.
This knowledge, earned by many a midnight vigil,
Has taught me that yon silver star is mine,
Which nightly, since I conn'd this wond'rous volume,
Hath dimm'd its fires, and warn'd me to forbear.
Yet have I still undaunted read, and now,
While pale and fitfully its beams shrink in,
The ingredients of a potent spell I mingle,
And but three drops of my own blood are wanting,
To give me proof that to my hests and bidding,
A spirit of dread ministry will come.
Why should the glorious planet fade at this?
Is there then peril to my better part
In this mysterious science? If I stop,
Haw shall I know the secrets written here
Are knowledge or phantasma? Can there be
Evil in truth? For to unfold the art
That summons spirits from their dark abode,
Is but to know what is -- and what the gods,
In their eternal mysteries have framed. -- 
Shrink into darkness thou faint trembling light,
I will abide the issues of the spell.
\end{verse}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make end-of-line `\\` :

[image]

```
\documentclass[ebook]{memoir}

\begin{document}


\linenumberfrequency{10}
\verselinenumbersleft

\begin{verse}\obeylines\let^^M\\%
Herman:
O'er every birth a star of fate presides,
And he that knows his orb of destiny,
May, by the changes of its radiance, tell
Whene'er his good or evil genius reigns.
This knowledge, earned by many a midnight vigil,
Has taught me that yon silver star is mine,
Which nightly, since I conn'd this wond'rous volume,
Hath dimm'd its fires, and warn'd me to forbear.
Yet have I still undaunted read, and now,
While pale and fitfully its beams shrink in,
The ingredients of a potent spell I mingle,
And but three drops of my own blood are wanting,
To give me proof that to my hests and bidding,
A spirit of dread ministry will come.
Why should the glorious planet fade at this?
Is there then peril to my better part
In this mysterious science? If I stop,
Haw shall I know the secrets written here
Are knowledge or phantasma? Can there be
Evil in truth? For to unfold the art
That summons spirits from their dark abode,
Is but to know what is -- and what the gods,
In their eternal mysteries have framed. -- 
Shrink into darkness thou faint trembling light,
I will abide the issues of the spell.
\end{verse}


\end{document}
```